# PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server

Tags: ruby, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my project to aws. after typing `eb create appname` I get following error message in log.

```
intializing git
  rake aborted!
  PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'


# sqlite3 fails on heroku
# group :development do
#    gem 'sqlite3'    #gem to use in development environment
# end
# gem 'sqlite3'
# group :production do
gem 'pg', '~> 0.20.0'         #gem to use in production environment
# end
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'devise'
gem 'nested_scaffold'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'activeadmin'
```

database.yml

```
development:
    adapter: postgresql
    host: localhost
    username: jusi
    database: odpdev


production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>  
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>  
  password: "<%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>" 
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>  
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

can anyone please troubleshoot. When I ssh to aws and type `psql` I get same error message. Result of `which postgres`

> /usr/bin/which: no postgres in (/home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.6.3/bin:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin)

Comment: Show us your postgres configuration.  Where does it run on what port?

Comment: where is configuration located?

Comment: http://blog.blackninjadojo.com/aws/elastic-beanstalk/2019/01/28/adding-a-database-to-your-rails-application-on-elastic-beanstalk-using-rds.html - change MySQL for Postgresql.

Comment: If you want to test your RDS connection you should pass all necessary options(like host, port, user, password and database name) to `psql`.

Comment: That depends where you installed it (did you actually install it?).  Your `yml` file suggests that you should have local instance for the DEV env and for the production you have an instance probably on some other server.

Comment: @Khtty Did you ever figure this out?